ASUS ROG STRIX G712LV bottom side LED
this problem is driving me crazy. I have newly installed Ubuntu 24.04 on my ASUS ROG STRIX G712LV machine and unfortunately I can't turn on the LEDs on the sides of the case as shown in the picture. The keyboard lights turn on without any problem, I tried rogauracore, openRGB, asusctl without success. And I specify that the lights in this part worked correctly when I was using Kali Linux.


If you want to see how this works you are at the wrong place: you need tools in Kali to find out what that system does and maybe you can copy it into Ubuntu,

Hi thank you very much but I'm not using Kali Linux now, I fulled(Not Virtualization) install Ubuntu on the Laptop.
